# Retrained model(test_new) from previously created keras-cnn-sequential model(test) has reduced size on local disk. Is this correct?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning

I had created created the model for 16 labelled images , all placed 1 local directory.This model size is 300MB on my local disk. Now I have incremented this existing model with 2 more label image types and placed them in same local directory along with previously 16 labelled images.This new model size on my local disk is only 100MB though its predicting correct output. Is it correctly built? I am not sure why size of this model is reduced.

Only change in code what I have done is in createModel method :-

```
        def createModel():
        #model = Sequential()
        #model.add(Conv2D(20,(5,5),padding="same",input_shape=inputShape)) 
        #model.add(Activation("relu"))
        #model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
        #model.add(Conv2D(50, (5, 5), padding="same"))
        #model.add(Activation("relu"))
        #model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
        #model.add(Flatten())
        #model.add(Dense(500))
        #model.add(Activation("relu"))
        #model.add(Dense(output_dim=16))
        #model.add(Activation("softmax"))
        model = load_model('test')
        model.pop()
        model.pop()
        for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False              
      model.add(Dense(output_dim=18,name='newDen',activation='softmax'))
        opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
        model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, 
        metrics= 
        ["accuracy"])
        return model
```

Earlier created the model using commented lines and then to retrain existing model I an deleting last 2 layers.